# drupal_get_form renders blank page

Tags: 7

I'm building a module for basic e-mail sharing that will present a form on every node. So I hook into nodes and add a new variable called `share_form` which is supposed to contain the from from `email_share_node_form` after it has been fetched with `drupal_get_form`.

I have been checking out loads of examples and as far as I can see I'm doing everything right. But the page turns completely blank, with no errors either in the reports or on the page. The same occurs when I use other form_ids such as `user_register_form` that is supposed to work.

If I add any normal string to `share_form` the page renders with no issues at all. So the error is definitely occuring inside `drupal_get_form`.

Is there obvious error in my code? How can I debug this?

**UPDATE:** If I put the `render(drupal_get_form('email_share_node_form'))` in my `node.tpl.php` it renders just fine. Why not in the module?

```
/**
 * Hook into node_load to insert an e-mail share form.
 */
function email_share_node_load($nodes, $types) {
  foreach ( $nodes as $nid => $node ) {
    $nodes[$nid]->share_form = drupal_get_form('email_share_node_form');
  }
}

// --------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Create a share-form to display on a node.
 */
function email_share_node_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit')
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have a white page then there is very likely an error somewhere. Check your apache or php error logs. Which could really be any where depend on what platform you are developing on.

Fatal errors won't make it into the database log file within Drupal since fatal errors tend to stop everything dead.

Comment: I get nothing in the PHP error log. But in the Apache log I found `[Fri Aug 12 11:53:38 2011] [notice] child pid 8421 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)`

Answer (score 0):

This is so late... Hope it helps someone...
I had the same problem with a white page and no errors reported.

In the form function you need need to `return drupal_get_form(`

I was simply calling `drupal_get_form(` and not returning it and had the exact same problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Druapl Answers. Thanks for the answer, could you please edit it and elaborate.